# Getting syntax error on my upgrade to RN 0.57 with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, react-native, babeljs

I'm attempting to upgrade my project which was using RN 0.56 + Typescript compiler using `react-native-typescript-transformer`

Now that the latest version of Babel supports Typescript, I've removed the TS compiler and attempted to use RN + Babel 7 to compile my code.

Though, I'm getting the following error:

```
error: bundling failed: SyntaxError: /Users/alexis.mangin/Workspace/zeos-native/packages/zeos-native-libs/ui/src/views/StickyTabView.tsx: Unexpected token, expected ")" (12:38)

  10 |
  11 | export interface IStickyTabViewProps {
> 12 |   renderTopNavigationBar: ({ opacity }: { opacity: Animated.AnimatedInterpolation }) => JSX.Element;
     |                                       ^
  13 |   renderHeader: () => JSX.Element;
  14 |   headerMinHeight: number;
  15 |   tabs: {
```

I've seen some people having the same issue here: https://github.com/ds300/react-native-typescript-transformer/issues/77

Though, even after removing all instances of the transformer, I still can't get my code running.

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

RN: 0.57.0
React: 16.5.0
Typescript: 3.0.3

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check your TSConfig; you probably need to enable destructuring via `downlevelIteration` set to `true`.